Trying to get PIC code to work
Relevant info can be found in this Google drive folder, breadboard is 1:1 with the schematic.
So, I've been scratching my head for the past few days to get this design to work, I tried to get some assistance from the two guys who were gonna get an A in this class and even they were stumped over how my code isn't working.
I've tested it across multiple PICs (16F84A), quadruple checked my code across four other students' code, ran continuity checks on EVERY relevant line on the breadboard, did the oscilloscope test (getting sine waves as an output), double checked every part, and I'm still getting nothing. I don't even care if the code looks messy and neither does the professor, this lab is required to have in-depth notes for every line, I just want to get this done so I can actually pass this class...
BTW, yes I made sure I clicked quick build after EVERY change I made before telling MPLAB to program the PIC.

please, no links to text and pictures ... add the code text to your post ... format as code ... add the images to your post directly, use the mountain icon

You should have a decoupling cap (100nF typical) across your supply pins 5 & 14. Probably just a labelling bug, but the positive supply is not Vss, it's Vdd (as shown in the datasheet).

It's been a while (decades ...?) since I last wrote assembler for a PIC16F84, but I'm suspicious of the way you're trying to write to the TRISA and TRISB registers. You start off with the BSF instruction I'd expect to see to set bit RP0 in the STATUS register which allows you to access the registers in Bank-1 using direct addressing - so I'm almost certain that you should be 0x05 and 0x06 for your TrisA and TrisB (yes, exactly the same as PortA and PortB), because by setting STATUS.RP0 you're telling the PIC to access Bank-1 registers starting at 0x80.

I'd also suggest that you use your Status definition in the BSF & BCF instructions in your "Setup" section instead of the 0x03 "magic number", and for bonus points, do a RP0 equ 0x05 up top along with Status and use that instead of the 0x05 "magic number" in those 2 instructions too.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@brhans I'm just going by what we were taught, which worked in previous labs, and I recycled the code just to ensure it would work every time.

brhans' hint on the addressing is most valuable. Just because you were not taught about that doesn't mean you can ignore it. The PIC is a real thing and cannot guess what you want. You might want to read and understand more of the PIC's documentation. BTW, even professors are humans and have errors. :-D
